# vuetify rows-per-page menu option dissapears

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use a v-data-table inside of a v-card, you can see the code from the following codepen

https://codepen.io/benwasin97/pen/eYveZGL

```
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :search="search"
        :sort-by="id"
        :sort-desc="true"
      >
```

When I click on the rows per page option the menu doesnt show up at all.. in my application, the whole rows per page dropdown menu does not show up entirely at all. So, Im hoping the issues might be correlated.

Just to recap, I am trying to make the rows per page menu show up in the codepen above.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `v-data-table` inside a `v-app`. If you do that, rows per page option would work.

Comment: I just the `v-app` tag around it, it didn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: In the codepen you sent, you have a ``</v-app>`` after the ‍‍``</v-col>``. So you only need to add ``<v-app>`` before the opening ``<v-col>`` tag.